# Procedência de cálculo

Tags: java, tipagem, matemática

Não consigo entender o por que de está dando 0.00 para o cálculo, sendo que se eu altero a ordem do cálculo da o valor esperado, o calculo tem apenas divisão e multiplicação.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n, i, animal, total = 0, totalRato = 0, totalSapo = 0, totalCoelho = 0; 
    double percentualCoelhos, percentualRatos, percentualSapos;
    char categoriaAnimal;
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc.nextInt();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        animal = sc.nextInt();
        categoriaAnimal = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (categoriaAnimal == 'R') {
            total += animal;
            totalRato += animal;
        }
        else if (categoriaAnimal == 'S') {
            total += animal;
            totalSapo += animal;
        }
        else if (categoriaAnimal == 'C') {
            total += animal;
            totalCoelho += animal;
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    percentualCoelhos = totalCoelho * 100.0 / total; 
    percentualRatos = totalRato / total * 100.0;
    percentualSapos = totalSapo / total * 100.0;
    System.out.println("Total: " + total + " cobaias");
    System.out.println("Total de coelhos: " + totalCoelho);
    System.out.println("Total de ratos: " + totalRato);
    System.out.println("Total de sapos: " + totalSapo);
    System.out.printf("Percentual de coelhos: %.2f%%%n", percentualCoelhos);
    System.out.printf("Percentual de ratos: %.2f%%%n", percentualRatos);
    System.out.printf("Percentual de sapos: %.2f%%%n", percentualSapos);
}

}
```

O problema está no código `percentualCoelhos = totalCoelho * 100.0 / total;` não vejo diferença de calcular dessa forma: `percentualCoelhos = totalCoelho / total * 100.0;`, porém o valor da diferente. Por que?

Comment: Porque totalCoelho e total são inteiros e a divisão entre inteiros é arredondada pra zero. Se quer que o resultado seja double, faça o cast: https://ideone.com/sYfGXB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é o sistema de tipagem.

A variável `total` é inteira e dependendo de onde ela esteja usará o operador de inteiro, que resulta em um inteiro e dependendo de onde ele tiver "contaminará" o próximo resultado para inteiro também. Se precedência (e não procedência) priorizar um valor do tipo `double` então o operador a ser usado é o `double` que resultará em um valor com parte decimal e poderá "contaminar" para a próxima operação com esse tipo também.

Então `totalCoelho * 100.0` dá um valor do tipo `double` (multiplicar um valor inteiro com um `double` dá um `double`), que será dividido depois por um valor inteiro, então significa que você quer um valor inteiro e é isso que resulta.

Já `totalRato / total` dá um inteiro por ambos são inteiros, há uma perda da parte fracionária (algumas pessoas consideram isso um erro da linguagem, mas é assim). Quando multiplica um inteiro com um `double`, o `* 100.0`, dá `double`, mas a perda já estava considerada.

Como você não disse o que espera como correto, não posso dizer qual é o que deseja, mas não importa se queria a perda da parte decimal então o segundo é o mais adequado, se não queria a perda o primeiro é o mais adequado.

Uma outra forma de resolver seria usar parênteses, assim muda a precedência.

Também pode forçar um tipo ser outro usando um *cast* transformando o tipo no que você quer.

Veja as diferenças:

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(123 * 100.0 / 10);
        System.out.println(123 * (100.0 / 10));
        System.out.println((double)123 * 100.0 / 10);       
        System.out.println(123 * 100.0 / (double)10);
        System.out.println(123 * 100 / 10);
        System.out.println(123 / 10 * 100.0);
        System.out.println(123 / (10 * 100.0));
        System.out.println((double)123 / 10 * 100.0);
        System.out.println(123 / (double)10 * 100.0);
        System.out.println(123 / 10 * 100);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CnVjDf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TypingPrecedencejava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Precedence.java).